# How to include citations in the rticles::jss function

Tags: r, r-markdown

Much thanks to the many authors of the  **rticles**  package in creating an Rmarkdown template  that allows me to get my article ready for submission to Journal of Statistical Software without leaving Rmarkdown environment. I have experience with R and Rmarkdown, but I don't have much experience with LaTex. After consulting the extensive JSS style guide, I wonder why no basic citation setup exists in the Rmarkdown jss template.

As my sources use the bibLaTex package, I want to use this citation package to handle my citations, and not the default "natbib" argument in  `rticles::jss`(). I can use "bibLaTex" because it is an an argument in `rticles::jss`(). I get an error compiling using **knitr**. The JSS documentation says to use the "\cite{}" commands instead of Rmarkdown default commands "[@ ... ]".  My markdown file, called "New_Template.Rmd", is shown below.

```
---
author:
  - name: FirstName LastName
    affiliation: University/Company
    address: >
      First line
      Second line
    email: \email{name@company.com}
    url: http://rstudio.com
  - name: Second Author
    affiliation: Affiliation
title:
  formatted: "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package \\pkg{foo}"
  # If you use tex in the formatted title, also supply version without
  plain:     "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package foo"
  # For running headers, if needed
  short:     "\\pkg{foo}: A Capitalized Title"
abstract: >
  The abstract of the article.
keywords:
  # at least one keyword must be supplied
  formatted: [keywords, not capitalized, "\\proglang{Java}"]
  plain:     [keywords, not capitalized, Java]
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
output: 
  rticles::jss_article:
    number_sections: TRUE     #added argument option 
    citation_package: biblatex  #All my citations use biblatex, not natbib. 
biblio-style: jss      #Added Citation style is listed to use in JSS Instructions for Authors.
bibliography: vignette_bib.bib  #Added here from template.
---

# Introduction

This template demonstrates some of the basic latex you'll need to know to create a JSS article.

A citation \citep{braunWhatCanEpidemiological2016} and not the RMarkdown style <!-- [@braunWhatCanEpidemiological2016] -->
```

Using the Rmarkdown citation [@braunWhatCanEpidemiological2016], knitting the New_Template.Rmd generates this error at the citation.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.53 A citation \autocite
                         {braunWhatCanEpidemiological2016} 

Error: Failed to compile New_Template.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See New_Template.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Clearly, the Rmarkdown syntax doesn't work. According to the JSS Author Guidelines, they suggested to use `\citep{...}~.  Using \citep{ braunWhatCanEpidemiological2016}, I get this error in printing the bibliography.

```
output file: New_Template.knit.md

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
l.112 \printbibliography

Error: Failed to compile New_Template.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See New_Template.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

[image: Here are additional files within my folder in compiling this Rmarkdown document.]

The specifications on the computer used to generate this code using `xfun::session_info('rticles')`

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, RStudio 1.1.463

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.13   glue_1.3.1      graphics_3.5.2  grDevices_3.5.2
  highr_0.8       htmltools_0.3.6 jsonlite_1.6    knitr_1.22      magrittr_1.5    markdown_0.9   
  methods_3.5.2   mime_0.6        Rcpp_1.0.1      rmarkdown_1.12  rticles_0.7.1   stats_3.5.2    
  stringi_1.4.3   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.11    tools_3.5.2     utils_3.5.2     xfun_0.6       
  yaml_2.2.0
```

Upon suggestion from error message to use `options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)` and `tinytex::pdflatex`(), I received the same error as above.

The first few lines of `New_Template.tex` look like this:

```
\documentclass[article]{jss}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
```

Interestingly, according to ["Bibliography management with biblatex"](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex), the LaTech file may be missing some code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{vignette_bib.bib}  %where "vignette_bib.bib" is the name of bibliography file
```

I was unable to LaTex the document because LaTexIt could not find the `jss.cls` object executing `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

I do expect that the Rmarkdown would compile and that the citations and bibliography would follow the JSS format. However, some differences in the citation style between using bibLaTex and natbib may exist.

Any suggestions in dealing with this issue would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/219